# how to implement file uploader to google drive web app code to hosted html site like instapage

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, google-drive-api

I am trying to implement the example code found on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication to my instapage site as an html code. Separately the web app works perfectly but after inserting it to instapage it fails to send the file to google drive.
Can you explain what did I do wrong? I was wondering if such an implemenation is possible at all. If not can you please let me know a workaround?

server.gs

```html
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function processForm(formObject) {
  var formBlob = formObject.myFile;
  var driveFile = DriveApp.createFile(formBlob);
  return driveFile.getUrl();
}
```

html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      function updateUrl(url) {
        var div = document.getElementById('output');
        div.innerHTML = '<a href="' + url + '">Got it!</a>';
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm">
      <input name="myFile" type="file" />
      <input type="button" value="Submit"
        onclick="google.script.run
            .withSuccessHandler(updateUrl)
            .processForm(this.parentNode)" />
    </form>
    <div id="output"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I also attach a screenshot about the instapage implementation I tried:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjDys.png)

Comment: After the site is deployed by instapage, is the html changed in any way? Is there a particular reason you are using instapage instead of another hosting service?